# Are there different colors of leptons?

Tags: standard-model, pauli-exclusion-principle, leptons

Are there different colors of [leptons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lepton)? The Pauli Exclusion principal made it necessary for quarks to have 3 different colors. However, although leptons don't undergo the strong interaction they still obey the Pauli Exclusion principal. But are there colors for leptons in a similar fashion as quarks?

Comment: Just look at the Wikipedia article for [leptons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lepton). It says: *"Color charge: No"*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows insufficient prior research.

Answer (score 5):

No, leptons are not coloured. The reason the Pauli principle requires colour is that there are particles made of 3 quarks that would otherwise all be in the same state, so we have to have this other quantum number, as not to violate Pauli (poor Pauli, people always trying to violate him).

Even if there was some state where some leptons were all packed together with the same quantum numbers, we wouldn't say that they have colour, because they don't interact through the strong (colour) force.

There are certain theories in which leptons are *themselves* another colour. This is the Pati-Salam model, where the colours are red, blue, green and lilac, where lilac = lepton, but this is a hypothetical theory designed to unify the strong force with others, and doesn't have anything to do with your question. Just a fun addition, I guess...

Comment: I share your sentiment...the violation of Pauli has become a goal of many physicists today.